# How can I display an image depending on the data in a looped array?

Tags: php

I've got a question that's a bit complicated and I'm not sure if there is a way to do it!

I have an array that consists of a variable number of 1s and 0s from a mysql query, I am displaying this data in a table using the following code;

```
 <?php
 for ($x=1; $x<=$detail['eventnumber']; $x++) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $events[$x] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $scores[$x] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 ?>
```

I'd like to be able to show an image in the table if the score is 1 and nothing if the score is 0. Is this possible? I've tried a few different methods but I can't seem to make it work.
Thank you!

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: `if ($whateverTheVariableIs == 1) { echo 'html with image'; }`...?!

Comment: I've tried that, I that because I'm generating a table based on the number of entries in the array it messes things up. If I'm wrong and there's a way to make it work I'd be delighted!

Comment: Show the code that you've tried e explain the error that is giving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($x=1; $x<=$detail['eventnumber']; $x++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $events[$x] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    if($scores[$x] == 1) {
        echo '<img src="image.jpg" />';
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! It worked, thank you so much. I'm not sure where I was going wrong but it doesn't matter now!